# Unit testing of a function that starts a go routine inside it

Tags: unit-testing, go, concurrency, goroutine, waitgroup

I have a codebase that is roughly as follows

```
type Service struct {
    Repo                 repo // An interface that contains both FunctionOne and FunctionTwo
    GoRoutineWaitgroup   *sync.WaitGroup
}

func (impl *Service) MyFunction(s string) bool {
    a := impl.Repo.FunctionOne()
    b := impl.Repo.FunctionTwo()
    fmt.Println("Executed Function One and Function two")
    go impl.validateMyFunction(a,b)
    return true

}

func (impl *Service) validateMyFunction(a string,b string) {
    defer helpers.PanicHandler()
    impl.GoRoutineWaitgroup.Add(1)
    defer impl.GoRoutineWaitgroup.Done()

    fmt.Println("a and b are validated")
}
```

---

And I wrote unit tests as something similar to this.

```
func TestMyFunction(t *testing.T) {

     ms := &Service{}

     test := []struct{
                 input string
                 output bool
                 case string
             }{
                 {"a", true, sample}
              }
     }

    for _, test := range tests {
        t.Run(test.case, func(t *testing.T) {

            mockRepo := new(mockrepo.Repo) // mockRepo contains mocks of original repo layer methods generated using mockery for testing purposes

            mockRepo.On("FunctionOne")
            mockRepo.On("FunctionTwo")

            ms.Repo = mockRepo

            op := ms.MyFunction(test.input)
            assert.Equal(t, test.Output, op)
        })
    }

} // Please keep in mind that this is not my actual code, but just a basic structure.
```

All tests are successful. But when executing the command `go test -v`, I saw multiple places in the code where the program panicked and gave `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`. I checked the code in debug mode and realized that the issue is with `impl.GoRoutineWaitgroup.Add(1)` in method `validateMyFunction` and when I commented out `go validateMyFunction(a,b)` and ran tests again, there were no panics in the logs. So How do I solve this issue? How to handle unit tests of functions where we start a goroutine from inside ( as in this case )?

Comment: Your `WaitGroup` is `nil` in the example code shown. Nothing ever initializes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need initialize value to `GoRoutineWaitgroup` field.

```golang
ms := &Service{GoRoutineWaitgroup: &sync.WaitGroup{}}
```

Or remove pointer from definition

```golang
type Service struct {
    Repo                 repo 
    GoRoutineWaitgroup   sync.WaitGroup
}
```

Also I do not see waiting for Wait Group in your code. Something like `ms.GoRoutineWaitgroup.Wait()` and you need to move impl.GoRoutineWaitgroup.Add(1) to `MyFunction` from `validateMyFunction` otherwise the code in `validateMyFunction` will not be called

Comment: Did this. Still getting the same issue. Do we have to do anything before doing `op := ms.MyFunction(test.input)`?

Comment: Perhaps you have a mistake somewhere in the repository. I deleted the repository, since I do not have the details of its implementation and you need to move `impl.GoRoutineWaitgroup.Add(1)` to `MyFunction`. I made a sample try it https://play.golang.org/p/PR-_u8uI-wY